# PL/SQL: I get expression 'I' cannot be used as an assignment target

Tags: plsql

My code:

```
create table info(str varchar2(30));

declare
cursor c(job emp_ast.job_id%type, dep emp_ast.department_id%type) is select employee_id
                                                                  from emp_ast
                                                                  where job_id=job and department_id=dep;
type t_job is table of emp_ast.job_id%type;
t t_job:=t_job();
emp emp_ast.employee_id%type;
i number(3);
begin
select job_id
bulk collect into t
from emp_ast;

for i in 10..270 loop
for j in 1..t.count loop
open c(i, t(j));
loop
fetch c into emp;
insert into info
values (i||' '||t(j)||' '||emp);
exit when c%notfound;
end loop;
i:=i+10;
end loop;
end loop;
end;
/
```

I get "expression 'I' cannot be used as an assignment target", reffering to the line where I increment i by 10. I am trying to save the department_id, employee_id and job_id as a string in a table for each department and each job.

Answer (score 2):

At the point where you get that message, `i` refers to the loop control variable `i` defined in the line `for i in 10..270 loop`, not the `int(3)` variable defined earlier. In PL/SQL a loop definition defines a variable which is only accessible inside the loop, and which you cannot alter. I suggest you change the name of one or the other to make them unique.

### EDIT

PL/SQL doesn't provide a way to step by more than 1 in a computed FOR loop. Instead, you will need to compute the desired department number value within the loop:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c(job EMP_AST.JOB_ID%TYPE,
           dep EMP_AST.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE)
    IS SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
         FROM EMP_AST
         WHERE JOB_ID = job AND
               DEPARTMENT_ID = dep;

  TYPE t_job IS TABLE OF EMP_AST.JOB_ID%TYPE;
  t t_job := t_job();

  emp          EMP_AST.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
  nDepartment  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT job_id
    BULK COLLECT INTO t
    FROM EMP_AST;
  
  FOR i IN 1..27 LOOP
    nDepartment := i * 10;

    FOR j IN 1..t.COUNT LOOP
      OPEN c(t(j), nDepartment);

      LOOP
        FETCH c INTO emp;
        
        INSERT INTO info
        VALUES (nDepartment || ' ' || t(j) || ' ' || emp);
        
        EXIT WHEN c%notfound;
      END LOOP;  -- cursor c 
      
      CLOSE c;
    END LOOP;  -- j
  END LOOP;  -- i
END;
/
```

Note that in the code above the `nDepartment` value is computed within the `i` loop, which now increments from 1 to 27 instead of going from 10 to 270.

Comment: I want to go from 10 in 10, that's why I am incrementing i by 10. My department_id's are like 10,20..270. How do I go about it?